# Listening to FormControl changes with ngOnChanges in the AppComponent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm attempting to listen to changes on a reactive email form control like this:

```
    import { Component, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
    })
    export class AppComponent  implements OnChanges {
      form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        email: new FormControl('',[ Validators.email ])
      });  


      get emailInput() { return this.form.get('email'); }

      ngOnChanges() {

      this.form.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        const formattedMessage = `Email is ${val}.`;
        console.log(formattedMessage);
      });
      }
    }
```

The form looks like this:

```
    <form [formGroup]="form">

      <input placeholder="Email" type="email" formControlName="email" >
    </form>
```

When typing in the email field nothing gets logged.  [This is the Stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onchanges-reactive-form-control)  Thoughts?

[This is the article the question implementation was based on](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-valuechanges/).

### Update

The accepted answer is to use the `ngOnInitit` lifecycle hook.  I wanted if perhaps it should be `ngAfterViewInit` just to make sure the view is entirely initialized or will be form bindings always be complete in `ngOnInit`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Didn't notice at first, but your `ngOnChanges` should not be where you are subscribing to the observable. `ngOnChanges` is for changes to input parameters to the current component (typically wrapped in `[]`).

Setup your subscription to the observable in the `ngOnInit` like this and your code will work:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.emailSubscription = this.form.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    const formattedMessage = `Email is ${val}.`;
    console.log(formattedMessage);
  });
}
```

Angular does not automatically unsubscribe so typically you'll want to save the value of the description, and then unsubscribe it in the ngOnDestroy:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.emailSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Since you're writing this code in appComponent there's probably not an explicit need to do this outside it being generally good practice for every *other* component.

Edit: Updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-onchanges-reactive-form-control-fhedj7) showing this working.

Comment: Awesome - Do you know by chance if Angular automatically unsubscribes this for us?

Comment: Also I wonder if it should perhaps be `ngAfterViewInit()` just to make sure the form is properly initialized?

Comment: @Ole Added an explanation about unsubscribe. You could do it in `ngAfterViewInit` if you like, but the results will be exactly the same. You've created the `FormGroup` when the component is instantiated, so `this.form.get('email').valueChanges` will always be available to be subscribed. Nothing is going to be updating that observable until the View is init'd anyway. `ngOnInit` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `onChanges` wrong. OnChanges watches for changes performed on a child component so that the parent component can update information. You're doing this with a form, so nothing will send changes up to the component.

Since the input is an element on the component, you can do it with an `(input)` listener or a `(keypress)`.